# Would this syntax correctly unsuspend a member?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a suspension command, but am not sure if it will correctly unsuspend after the amount of time is over. I want to use 1m/30s/5h/2d to suspend after the prefix, but it doesn't unsuspend. I'm not sure if I waited long enough, however it doesn't respond or create an error.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('✪ Commissioner ✪', '✪ Vice Commissioner ✪', '✪ Board of Directors ✪')
async def suspend(ctx, member:discord.Member, time, *, reason):
    guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
    role_name = 'Suspended'
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Suspended')
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
 
    embed.add_field(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> **Success!**', value=f'{member.mention} has been successfully suspended for {time} for {reason}')
    
    # Defile the "role" variable
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(766647041483866132)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    # Using asyncio module to wait
    expired = await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    thing = discord.Embed(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> Suspension Expired', value=f"{member.mention}'s suspension is over.")
    await expired.send(embed=thing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```py
expired = await asyncio.sleep(time)
await member.remove_roles(role)
thing = discord.Embed(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> Suspension Expired', value=f"{member.mention}'s suspension is over.")
await expired.send(embed=thing) # expired isn't a messageable...

# -------------------------------------------------------------
# To fix this, you can use ctx.send instead.

expired = await asyncio.sleep(time)
await member.remove_roles(role)
thing = discord.Embed(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> Suspension Expired', value=f"{member.mention}'s suspension is over.")
await ctx.send(embed=thing)
```